# How to create a model with multi-store attributes?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, model

I want to show data on the product's pages to the customer. This data is related to multiple products and it is multilingual.

So I want to create a new model in Magento with this data, how do I create multilingual (multistore) attributes for this model?

I could look at the Product model, but I would prefer not to use EAV, because the attributes are static.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are not using Magento's default product attributes functionality?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Because the data is related to multiple products. So to keep it maintainable, I need to separate the data from the product data and link it to products.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions would be using static blocks. You can create custom product attribute which will use source model that renders a list of available static blocks. Then, based on selection, you can render such static block on frontend. That static block may contain mutual data that you want to reuse on different products.

Other solution would be creating coa mplete entity, either with flat or eav structure. By nature, it will act like static block, but with single line entries. And then you can map those entries via source model to the custom attribute, and render its value.